# ¿Cómo hacer que los usuarios puedan sobreescribir un archivo que cargan en un sitio web (antes ya había un archivo)?

Tags: html

Estoy tratando de hacer un sitio web para que los usuarios puedan descargar un archivo, firmarlo digitalmente y sobreescribir el archivo anterior con uno que incluya su firma (así van a hacer varios usuarios). Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="background-color: #abdfd6;">
<a href="NombreGenerico.pdf">Descargar PDF para firmar</a>
<form action="/ruta/de/destino/procesamiento" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="archivo">
<input type="submit" value="Subir archivo">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo tengo dentro del Administrador de Archivos de webhost, en la siguiente ruta: "/public_html/index.html".

¿Cómo hago para que los usuarios puedan descargar el archivo, firmarlo digitalmente y sobreescribir el archivo anterior con uno que incluya su firma (así van a hacer varios usuarios)?

Comment: Todo eso claramente no se puede hacer en HTML... que lenguajes de back estas usando? que intentaste???

Comment: Tendrías que crear un script con JavaScript o PHP.  Proporciona mas código para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @gbianchi No sé nada de backend, solo sé un poco de Python.

Comment: Es difícil si no sabes nada de back. La lógica "más fácil" sería: `Antes de guardar el nuevo archivo > Recuperar el antiguo y eliminarlo > Luego subir el nuevo ya firmado`

Comment: @OCHOA No logré que los archivos subidos por los usuarios se guarden. Entiendo que se debería guardar en el Administrador de Archivos del sitio web en la ruta /public_html/index.html

Comment: Para eso, necesitas que un backend reciba el archivo y haga el guardado correspondiente. Investiga sobre eso, no podemos ayudarte mucho mas...